# How to convert a nested list into a dataframe?

Tags: python, r, excel

I have a long list of parts that are bulleted in a word doc. I need to turn this into a data table.

Example Input List:

```
= Fasteners

    o Screws

        - Machine

            +Round Head

            +Pan Head

            +Flat Head

       - Tapping

            +Type AB

            +Type A
```

Example Output Table: Thanks for looking!!

```
Parent   |Child |Type   |Style                               
Fasteners|Screws|Machine|Round Head    
Fasteners|Screws|Machine|Pan Head    
Fasteners|Screws|Machine|Flat Head    
Fasteners|Screws|Tapping|Type AB    
Fasteners|Screws|Tapping|Type A
```

etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can convert the bullet points into a Python dictionary (as this would probably be the best way to store everything if it's nested):

```
import pandas as pd

parts = {  
     'Fasteners':{  
        'Screws':{  
           'Machine':['Round Head','Pan Head','Flat Head'],
           'Tapping':['Type AB','Type A']
        }
     }
}

df_dict = {'Parent': [], 'Child': [], 'Type': [], 'Style': []}
for parent, v1 in parts.items():
    for child, v2 in v1.items():
        for child_type, v3 in v2.items():
            for style in v3:
                df_dict['Parent'].append(parent)
                df_dict['Child'].append(child)
                df_dict['Type'].append(child_type) # Not named type because type is a native Python function
                df_dict['Style'].append(style)

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
print(df)
```

Pandas works best when creating a dataframe if you have a dictionary where each key is the column and each value is a list of values (in order with each other). What I'm doing here is looping through every key and value in the nested dictionary so that I can generate the list, repeating where necessary (in a way that's easy to understand). The `parts.items()` creates an iterator for a dictionary where it will loop through every key and its corresponding value. Here's the output:

```
      Parent   Child     Type       Style
0  Fasteners  Screws  Machine  Round Head
1  Fasteners  Screws  Machine    Pan Head
2  Fasteners  Screws  Machine   Flat Head
3  Fasteners  Screws  Tapping     Type AB
4  Fasteners  Screws  Tapping      Type A
```